# error on save for mongoose--userScheema.pre('save')

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose, bcrypt

I am basically getting an eror when i am using userSchema.pre('save',asyn()) in typescript

The exact error is
Error:
No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Argument of type '"save"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RegExp | "insertMany"'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(409, 5): The last overload is declared here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRFeH.png)

i tried explore index.d.ts but i am a begineer to typescript so.*

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from "mongoose";
import { IUser } from "./modelTypes.js";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { NextFunction } from "express";


const userSchema: Schema<IUser> = new Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Username is required"],
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
      trim: true,
      index: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Password is required"],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Email is required"],
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    fullname: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Fullname is required"],
      trim: true,
      index: true,
    },
    avatar: {
      type: String, //cloudinary url
      required: [true, "Avatar is required"],
    },
    coverImage: {
      type: String, //cloudinary url
    },
    watchHistory: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Video",
      },
    ],
    refreshToken: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

userSchema.pre('save',async function(next: NextFunction) {

  if (!this.isModified("password")) return next();

  try{
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
  next();
}
  catch{
    const err = new Error('something went wrong');
    // If you call `next()` with an argument, that argument is assumed to be
    // an error.
    next(err);
  }
});

const User = mongoose.model<IUser>("User", userSchema);
```

index.d.ts file line 409

```
pre<T = TModelType>(
      method: 'insertMany' | RegExp,
      fn: (
        this: T,
        next: (err?: CallbackError) => void,
        docs: any | Array<any>,
        options?: InsertManyOptions & { lean?: boolean }
      ) => void | Promise<void>
    ): this;
    pre<T = TModelType>(
      method: 'insertMany' | RegExp,
      options: SchemaPreOptions,
      fn: (
        this: T,`your text`
        next: (err?: CallbackError) => void,
        docs: any | Array<any>,
        options?: InsertManyOptions & { lean?: boolean }
      ) => void | Promise<void>
    ): this;

    /** Object of currently defined query helpers on this schema. */
    query: TQueryHelpers;
```